# Realizing if there is a pattern in a string (Does not need to start at index 0, could be any length)

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

Coding a program to detect a *n*-length pattern in a string, even without knowing where the pattern starts, could be easily done by creating a list of *n*-length substrings and check if starting at one point there are same items or the rest of the list. Without any piece of information other than the string to check through, is the only way to recognize the pattern is to brute-force through all lengths and check or is there a more efficient algorithm?

(I'm just a beginner in Python, so this may be easy to code... )

Current code that only suits checking for starting at index 0:

```
def search(s):
    match=s[0]+s[1]

    while (match != s) and (match[0] != match[-1]):
        for matchLen in range(len(match),len(s)-1):
            letter = s[matchLen]
            if letter == match[-1]:
                match += s[len(match)]
                break

    if match == s:
        return None

    else:
        return match[:-1]
```

Comment: You have the `string` and the `pattern` right? I am not able to understand the second part of your question. You want to extract a pattern from the given string?

Comment: What is a pattern? Is `abcdeabcde` one?

Comment: @RahulNori Yes... I want to *not be* given how long the pattern is and still recognize if there is a pattern.

Comment: @QianLi But do you know *what* the pattern is?

Comment: @ppperry Yes, `abcde` is repeating.

Comment: Does the pattern have a property?

Comment: @RahulNori I don't really understand what you mean by "property"?

Comment: @pzp No. I don't even know the LENGTH of the pattern!

Comment: @QianLi You can know what the pattern is without knowing its length. Using @ppperry's example, you know that the pattern is ``abcde``, but you don't know that the length of the pattern in the string, ``adcdeabcde``, is 10.

Comment: Regardless, edit your question to include the code that you tried if you want to be helped. Not only will it show people that you put in the effort to try to solve your problem on your own, but it will also make your question much clearer as we'll know exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall(r'(.{2,})\1+', string)`. The parentheses creates a capture group that is later backreferenced by \1. The `.` matches any character (except for line breaks). The `{2,}` requires the pattern to be at least two characters long (otherwise strings like `ss` would be considered a pattern). Finally the `+` requires that pattern to repeat 1 or more times (in addition to the first time that it occurred inside the capture group). You can [see it working in action](http://pythex.org/?regex=(.%7B2%2C%7D)%5C1%2B&test_string=abcabc%0Ananana%0Aabcdefabcdef%0A123412&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Answer (score 0):

Pattern is a far too vague term, but assuming you mean some string repeating itself, the regexp `(?P<pat>.+)(?P=pat)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all matches:

```
import re 

s = "somethingabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeelseabcdeabcdeabcde"

li = re.findall(r'abcde',s)

print(li)
```

Output:

```
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde']
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a string what you could do is -

You start with `length = 1`, and take two pointer variables `i` and `j` which you shall use to traverse the string.

```
Set i = 0 and j = i+length
if str[i]==str[j]:
  i++,j++ // till j not equal to length of string 
else:
  length = length + 1 
  //increase length by 1 and start the algorithm over from i = 0
```

Take the example `abcdeabcde` :

In this we see
Initially `i = 0, j = 1` ,
but `str[0]!=str[1]` i.e. `a!=b`,
Then we get `length = 2` i.e., `i = 0,j = 2`
but `str[0]!=str[2]` i.e. `a!=c`,

Continuing in the same fashion,
We see when `length = 5` and `i = 0 and j = 5`,
`str[0]==str[5]`
and thus you can see that `i` and `j` increment till `j` is equal to string length.
And you have your answer that is the pattern length. It may not seem obvious but i would suggest you dry-run this algorithm over some of your test cases and let me know the results.